# Suppressing figure numbers in KOMA-Script captions

Tags: captions, koma-script

I am in the process of replacing the `caption` package with KOMA-Script in a long document. Where `caption` allows me to suppress the figure-number at the start of any caption by using `\caption*{text}`, I see nothing comparable in the KOMA-Script documentation. Can someone enlighten me?

**Edit**: I would like to suppress the whole "Figure x.y:" marker before the actual caption text, just as `caption*` does.

Comment: But `\caption*` not only suppresses the number; it also suppresses the label ("Figure" or "Table").

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: That's true, and that's what I would like. I'll edit to make that clear.

Comment: Ah, then I'll un-delete my answer ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I could see in the documentation, there's no build-in equivalent to `\caption*` in the `KOMA` classes, but `KOMA` gives you the tools to easily define such a command:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\WLcaption[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\figureformat}{}
  \renewcommand*{\tableformat}{}
  \renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}
  \addtocounter{\@captype}{-1}
  \caption{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{2cm}
\WLcaption{A test caption without label for a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{2cm}
\caption{A test caption with label for a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{2cm}
\WLcaption{A test caption without label for a table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{2cm}
\caption{A test caption with label for a table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean to use a KOMAScript class by "replacing 'caption' with koma" you could simply redefine `\figureformat` :

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}   
\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{}

\begin{figure}
\caption{x}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

will strip the whole label.

Comment: Thanks. Some authors prefer captions alone to appear with figures, without figure numbers. Go figure.

Comment: But this still leaves the separator (`:` by default.)

Comment: yeah i see i removed it accidentally