# Suppressing figure numbers in wrapfig

Tags: captions, wrapfigure

Like @brannerchinese [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66099/suppressing-figure-numbers-in-koma-script-captions), I'd like to suppress the figure numbers for certain figures, but I'd like to do it within the context of the `wrapfig` and `wrapfigure` package/environment.

Being rather new at this, I don't really understand the answer that @GonzaloMedina gave him, so I can't generalize that, but I did try blindly copying and pasting the `\newcommand\WLcaption[1]{` (et. al.) into my preamble just in case, and as I guessed, it didn't work (compile failed with error). Also tried `\caption*{text}` in case that had been implemented for `wrapfig` but also no joy.

Any ideas on how to do this? I just want a caption for some figures, but no figure numbers.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code shows three options, all of them using features provided by the `caption` package: the first one, uses `\caption*`; the second one uses `\captionsetup` to declare the predefined `labelformat=empty` style to suppress the label; the third option uses `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` to define a caption format without number but keeping the "Figure" label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{nonumber}{#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
\centering
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption*{Test figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
\centering
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{Test figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
\centering
\captionsetup{labelformat=nonumber}
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{Test figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]