# Second caption in KOMA-Script without entrance in the listoftables

Tags: captions, koma-script

I use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66099/suppressing-figure-numbers-in-koma-script-captions) Method to to get a caption in KOMA-script that behaves like the caption* of the caption package. Because I use this command for explanatory remarks of tables and figures, I don’t want an entry in the listoftables. How do I get rid of it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=11,oneside,appendixprefix,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\WLcaption[1]{%
    \renewcommand*{\figureformat}{}
    \renewcommand*{\tableformat}{}
    \renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}
    \addtocounter{\@captype}{-1}
    \caption{#1}}
\makeatother
%\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \listoftables
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \captionabove{Reform threshold as a function of the degree of risk aversion}

    \begin{tabular}{| c  c|  c  c | p{5cm} |}
        \hline
        \textbf{Risk aversion \(\gamma\)} & \textbf{Reform threshold \(\tau\)} \\ \hline
        0 &  48.3 \\ \hline
        1 &  55.2 \\ \hline
        2 &  61.0 \\ \hline
        3 &  65.9 \\ \hline
        4 &  69.9 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}  

    \WLcaption{\textit{Note:} Some Note without number but unfortunately with an entrance in the list of tables}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply place the note below the tabular:

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=11,oneside,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\WLcaption[1]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    #1
        \end{minipage}
}

\makeatother
%\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \listoftables
\begin{table}

    \centering
    \captionabove{Reform threshold as a function of the degree of risk aversion}

    \begin{tabular}{| c  c|  c  c | p{5cm} |}
        \hline
        \textbf{Risk aversion \(\gamma\)} & \textbf{Reform threshold \(\tau\)} \\ \hline
        0 &  48.3 \\ \hline
        1 &  55.2 \\ \hline
        2 &  61.0 \\ \hline
        3 &  65.9 \\ \hline
        4 &  69.9 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}  

        \WLcaption{\textit{Note:} Some Note without number but unfortunately with an entrance in the list of tables}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was too focused on the caption command to see this easy solution. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterStrawson You're welcome!